# Show only the combinations of two permutated arrays that have a sum less than or equal to target number

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations

I have two arrays:
`teams = [1,2,3]` and  `drivers = [4,5,6]`. Using permutations I have managed to show all combinations of the two arrays, but have managed to define what number of values I'd like to use from each array. So from 'Teams' I have used 1 value and 'Drivers' I have used two. I would like to only show the combinations where the sum is less than or equal to 10 and remove any duplicates.

```
    teams = [1,2,3]
    drivers = [4,5,6]
    team = teams.permutation(1).to_a
    driver = drivers.permutation(2).to_a
    array = team.product(driver)
    target = 11
```

This is successfully outputting all combinations of the two arrays using 1 number from teams and 2 from drivers as follows:

`[[1], [4, 5]], [[1], [4, 6]], [[1], [5, 4]], [[1], [5, 6]], [[1], [6, 4]], [[1], [6, 5]], [[2], [4, 5]],` etc...

To only show values less than or equal to 10 my expected outcome would be: `[[1], [4, 5]], [[1], [5, 4]],`

and then no duplicates would leave me with just:
`[[1], [4, 5]]`

I have tried adding the below line of code but am getting an ***undefined method `<='*** error:

`@array = array[0].product(*array[1..-1]).select { |a| a.reduce(:+) <= target }`

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
result = array.combination(1).select{|combi| combi.sum <= target}

@array = result
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the permutation?

Comment: Are are elements known to be non-negative?

Comment: I understand what it means to be the **combination of one array** or **combination of a set** (= rearranging the array elements in some way, without respect to the order), but what do you mean by combination of **two** arrays? In your example you seem to construct an _array of pairs_, but I don't get the rule according to which this array of pairs should be constructed.

Comment: If the order of drivers doesn't matter (i.e. `[4, 5]` is equivalent to `[5, 4]`), you might want `drivers.combination(2)`. Can you explain what theses numbers and their sums are about? What does it mean for a team to be a `1` and for a driver to be a `4` or `5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach

```
teams = [1, 2, 3]
drivers = [2, 6, 5, 4]
team = teams.permutation(1).to_a
driver = drivers.permutation(2).to_a
array = team.product(driver)

target = 10

res = array.select {|i| i.map(&:sum).sum <= target}.compact
==> [[[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 4]], [[1], [6, 2]],
     [[1], [5, 2]], [[1], [5, 4]], [[1], [4, 2]], [[1], [4, 5]],
     [[2], [2, 6]], [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 4]], [[2], [6, 2]],
     [[2], [5, 2]], [[2], [4, 2]], [[3], [2, 5]], [[3], [2, 4]],
     [[3], [5, 2]], [[3], [4, 2]]]
```

Getting the unique items (modified to also work for values of teams > drivers)

```
t1 = res.map {|i| i[0]}
d2 = res.map {|i| i[1].flatten.sort}

t1.zip(d2).uniq
==> [[[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 4]], [[1], [4, 5]],
     [[2], [2, 6]], [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 4]], [[3], [2, 5]],
     [[3], [2, 4]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Andre this gave me the outcome I was looking for perfectly!

Comment: @CarySwoveland One of my assumptions is that max teams is always <= min drivers as in the example given. Otherwise flatten sort has to involve one or two more substeps. I will incorporate a hook to circumvent that scenario. Thanks for testing and catching that!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I get [[[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 4]], [[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 7]], [[1], [4, 5]], [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 4]], [[2], [2, 6]], [[3], [2, 5]], [[3], [2, 4]]]

Comment: My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry I was just using 1,2,3 in teams just so I could clearly see if the code was working. Teams and drivers could have any value

Comment: @ldthompson No worries, works now with any value :)

Comment: Note that it would be more efficient to replace `permutation(2)` with `combination(2)` and it might be clearer to write `team = teams.map { |t| [t] }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
teams = [1,2,3]
drivers = [2,5,4,5,6,4,5,7]
max_driver_sum = 10
```

I have assumed that `drivers` can contain duplicate elements (as in my example), but I will explain at the end how the calculations would simplify if there are no duplicates.

---

As a first step let's partition `drivers` between values that are repeated and those that are not.

```
counts = drivers.tally
  #=> {2=>1, 5=>3, 4=>2, 6=>1, 7=>1}

dup_drivers, uniq_drivers = counts.partition { |_d,n| n > 1 }
                                  .map { |arr| arr.map(&:first) }​
  #=> [[5, 4], [2, 6, 7]]
```

​Therefore,

```
dup_drivers
  #=> [5, 4]

uniq_drivers    
  #=> [2, 6, 7]
```

See [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) and [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

Here,

```
counts.partition { |_d,n| n > 1 } 
 #=> [[[5, 3], [4, 2]], [[2, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1]]]
```

---

First compute the unique combinations in which the two drivers are equal:

```
dup_combos = teams.each_with_object([]) do |t,arr|
  max_driver = (max_driver_sum - t)/2
  dup_drivers.each do |d|
    arr << [[t],[d,d]] if d <= max_driver
  end
end
  #=> [[[1], [4, 4]], [[2], [4, 4]]]
```

---

Next, compute the unique combinations in which the two drivers are not equal:

```
all_uniq = uniq_drivers + dup_drivers
  #=> [2, 6, 7, 5, 4]
```

```
all_uniq_combos = all_uniq.combination(2).to_a
  #=> [[2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 5], [2, 4], [6, 7], [6, 5],
  #    [6, 4], [7, 5], [7, 4], [5, 4]]
```

```
uniq_combos = teams.each_with_object([]) do |t,arr|
  adj_driver_sum = max_driver_sum - t
  all_uniq_combos.each do |combo|
    arr << [[t],combo] if combo.sum <= adj_driver_sum
  end
end
  #=> [[[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 7]], [[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 4]],
  #   [[1], [5, 4]], [[2], [2, 6]], [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 4]],
  #   [[3], [2, 5]], [[3], [2, 4]]]
```

See [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-combination).

---

The final step is to combine the two groups of combinations:

```
a1 = dup_combos + uniq_combos
  #=> [[[1], [4, 4]], [[2], [4, 4]], [[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 7]],
  #    [[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 4]], [[1], [5, 4]], [[2], [2, 6]],
  #    [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 4]], [[3], [2, 5]], [[3], [2, 4]]]
```

Sorted, this result is as follows.

```
a1.sort
  #=> [[[1], [2, 4]], [[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 7]],
  #    [[1], [4, 4]], [[1], [5, 4]],
  #    [[2], [2, 4]], [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 6]], [[2], [4, 4]],
  #    [[3], [2, 4]], [[3], [2, 5]]]
```

Notice that [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) was not used in the foregoing. If desired, one could of course substitute out some of the variables above.

---

If `drivers` contains no duplicates the desired array is given by `uniq_combos` where `all_uniq` is replaced by `drivers` in the calculation of `all_uniq_combos`. If, for example,

```
teams = [1,2,3]
drivers = [2,5,4,6,7]
max_driver_sum = 10
```

then

```
all_uniq_combos = drivers.combination(2).to_a
  #=> [[2, 5], [2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 7], [5, 4], [5, 6],
  #    [5, 7], [4, 6], [4, 7], [6, 7]]

combos = teams.each_with_object([]) do |t,arr|
  adj_driver_sum = max_driver_sum - t
  all_uniq_combos.each do |combo|
    arr << [[t],combo] if combo.sum <= adj_driver_sum
  end
end ​
  #=> [[[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 4]], [[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 7]],
  #    [[1], [5, 4]], [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 4]], [[2], [2, 6]],
  #    [[3], [2, 5]], [[3], [2, 4]]]

combos.sort
  #=> [[[1], [2, 4]], [[1], [2, 5]], [[1], [2, 6]], [[1], [2, 7]],
  #    [[1], [5, 4]],
  #    [[2], [2, 4]], [[2], [2, 5]], [[2], [2, 6]],
  #    [[3], [2, 4]], [[3], [2, 5]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Cary, your walk through was great and definitely showed me a lot of methods/options that I never knew existed and will be very useful!

Comment: idthompson, I revised my answer because I realised that I had misunderstood the max sum requirement. My original answer reflected my incorrect assumption that the max sum only concerned the drivers, not the sum of the team and drivers. I now see that the latter is what you want, though the rationale for including a team number in the sum is not evident.

Comment: hi, The other answer which I posted is incorrect. I have deleted that post.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks! Sorry if I wasn’t  clear, and Teams and Drivers could have any value. I was just using 1,2,3 as an example so I could see if the code was working properly, thanks!

Comment: Could you have `teams = [1,1,1]; drivers = [1,1,1]`, in which case there would be just one combination, `[[1],[1,1]]`?